# How to evaluate solenoid valve specifications

Tags: electrical-engineering, valves

I need to replace a solenoid valve, and I need help in identifying the specifications that I should check for an equivalent replacement.

This is a picture of the valve itself:

[image: solenoid valve]
<sub>*Click for larger image*</sub>

If it matters, the valve is used to control water flow with a whole house humidifier.  The required inlet and outlet pipe sizes are understandably constrained by the existing piping.

[This site](http://www.achrnews.com/articles/92540-understanding-solenoid-valves) provides a good overview of the terminology involved, but also mentions a few terms that aren't listed on the label.  Their review is echoed by [this site](http://controltrends.org/by-industry/commercial-hvac/actuators-and-valves/01/solenoid-valve-basics/), which covers many of the same terms.

My online searching has yielded a couple of suggested equivalent parts, as well as a different version of the value offered by the OEM of the humidifier.  Some of the suggested equivalent parts are roughly half the price of the OEM replacement part.  But I would like to make sure that I'm truly buying an equivalent part.

What specifications do I need to verify before purchasing a replacement solenoid valve?

Comment: Please post a photo of the entire valve.

Answer (score 2):

You need verify that your replacement has:

- 1/16" orifice(commonly available)
- Now, what are the size of the theads on the inlet and outlet(1/8" npt?) it might be stamped somewhere on the valve body. Also, unscrew the 90deg adapter and check.
- 24/60 would indicate 24volts AC at 60Hz.(not very common) If you can check the two lines connecting the solenoid with a multimeter you can verify this yourself.
- the wattage of the valve: 6 watts?(hard to see)
- it looks like a standard brass housing
- Normally Open or Normally Closed? (NO, NC) When NOT energized, is there flow through the valve?
- Is it suitable/designed for your application? Water.

Once you can answer all of these questions, you can easily find a replacement valve.

Also, check ebay/google/amazon by description of part/machine/Serial Numbers on valve and/or by valve specifications. You'll likely find what you need there as well. I did a quick search and found several likely replacements.